# How to fix ngx data table column width with column mode is 'force'

Tags: typescript, bootstrap-4, angular8, ngx-datatable, column-width

im using ngx data table. in that im having no of columns. by default its took defult with and it goes more than grid with scroll bar. i tried with columns array with width.

```
  displayColumns = [
    { name: 'S.No', value: 'SNo', width: '10' }, { name: 'Item', value: 'ProductName' , width: '10'  },
    { name: 'HSN Code', value: 'HCNCode', width: '10'  }, { name: 'GST%', value: 'GSTRate', width: '100'  },
    { name: 'Touch', value: 'PTouch', width: '10'  },
    { name: 'Qty', value: 'Quantity', width: '10'  }, { name: 'MCP Rate', value: 'MCPRate', width: '10'  }, 
    { name: 'MCP Amt', value: 'MCPAmount', width: '10'  },
    { name: 'Weight', value: 'Weight', width: '10'  }, { name: 'MCG Rate', value: 'MCGRate', width: '10'  },
     { name: 'MCG Amt', value: 'MCGAmount', width: '10'  },
    { name: 'Wastage', value: 'STouch', width: '10'  }, { name: 'Purity', value: 'Purity', width: '10'  }, { name: 'Total MC', value: 'TotalMC', width: '10'  },
    { name: 'Gram Rate', value: 'Rate', width: '10'  }, { name: 'Total Amt', value: 'TotalAmount' , width: '10' },
    { name: 'Actions', value: 'Actions' }];
```

and my table is

```
   <ngx-datatable class="bootstrap" [rows]="roleList" [headerHeight]="80"
                                        [footerHeight]="50" [rowHeight]="'45'" [scrollbarH]="true"
                                        [columnMode]="'force'" [limit]="limit" [loadingIndicator]="loadingIndicator"
                                        [columns]="displayColumns" [reorderable]="reorderable">
                                        <ngx-datatable-column *ngFor="let column of displayColumns"
                                            [name]="column.name">
                                            <ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-rowIndex="rowIndex"
                                                let-value="value" let-row="row">
                                                <span class="badge fw-default"
                                                    [ngClass]="{'badge-success': row[column.value] === 'Yes', 'badge-danger': row[column.value] === 'No' }"
                                                    *ngIf="column.name !== 'Actions'">{{row[column.value]}}</span>
                                                <span *ngIf="column.name === 'Actions'">
                                                    <button class="btn btn-primary mr-1 btn-fab" placement="top"
                                                        ngbTooltip="Edit" [disabled]=financedisabled
                                                        (click)="edit(row)">
                                                        <i class="ft-edit"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                    <button class="btn btn-warning mr-1 btn-fab" placement="top"
                                                        ngbTooltip="Delete" [disabled]=financedisabled
                                                        (click)="deleteRow(row)">
                                                        <i class="ft-trash-2"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                    <button class="btn btn-success mr-1 btn-fab" placement="top"
                                                        ngbTooltip="Permission" [disabled]=financedisabled
                                                        (click)="routeToRolePermission(row)">
                                                        <i class="ft-edit"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                </span>
                                            </ng-template>
                                        </ngx-datatable-column>
                                    </ngx-datatable>
```

width no taking with specified in columns array. im getting grid like bellow
[actually grid having like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iigK6.png)

and expecting grid like bellow
[expecting grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtdjP.png)

as shown expecting grid having with drag-gable header .. so could u please say how to fix column width in this scenario. i tried many ways could no fix it .

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to set a fixed width for your columns. I would do it like this:

```
<ngx-datatable-column *ngFor="let column of displayColumns" [name]="column.name" [width]="100">
<!-- the rest of your code -->
</ngx-datatable-column>
```